# How to display a formatted date in OctoberCMS backend form?

Tags: octobercms

I'm trying to display a formatted date value in a form field using the example in the docs:
https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#column-datetime

```
created_at:
    label: Date
    type: datetime
    format: l jS \of F Y h:i:s A
```

This raises the exception:
`modules/backend/Widgets/form/partials/_field_datetime.htm" not found.`

I also tried changing the type to `datepicker`. No exception is thrown, but the date value is not formatted.

Any ideas on how to display a date formatted as `d/m/Y`?

**Edit:**

I actually need an editable date input field in the form, preferably a `datepicker`, where a user could select a date using the `datepicker` or type a date in a format they are familiar with, e.g. `d/m/Y` and have the typed value applied to the form field.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a `partial` type

For a list

```
created_at:
    label: Date
    type: partial
    path: column_date
```

With the following code inside **_column_date.htm**

```
<?= $value->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') ?>
```

For a form

```
created_at:
    label: Date
    type: partial
    path: field_date
```

With the following code inside **_field_date.htm**

```
<?= $formModel->created_at->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Samuel, thanks for your answer. It works for displaying the field value, but actually I need an input where a user can type the date using a format they are familiar with `d/m/Y` and have that value applied to the form field. I updated my question to make it more clear.

It seems you use https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday that has a `format` property. How can I set the `format` to the OctoberCMS datepicker instance?

Comment: Not supported as far as I know. Try logging an issue for it on GitHub.

Comment: Please review and merge if you agree: https://github.com/octobercms/october/pull/1919

Answer (score 3):

Add "format" to you config_list.yaml

```
 start_at:
        label: My Label
        type: dateTime
        format: j M Y H:I
```